# Why does the 2nd function return undefined?

Tags: javascript

I have 2 JavaScript functions that return the same object, upon calling both functions one after another, why does the 2nd function return `undefined`?

```
function foo1()
{
  return {
      bar: "hello"
  };
}

function foo2()
{
  return
  {
      bar: "hello"
  };
}

console.log(foo1());
console.log(foo2());

// foo1 returns:
// Object {bar: "hello"}
// foo2 returns:
// undefined
```

Comment: You're calling "foo" instead of "foo2"?

Comment: Corrected @AarónBC.

Answer (score 3):

Because automatic semicolon insertion puts a semicolon right after `return`.

That second function gets turned into:

```
function foo2() {
  return; // since no value is mentioned, undefined is returned
  {  // This is the start of a block, not an object
    bar: 'hello'; // bar is a line label, not a key in an object.
  }
}
```

If you want to have your return statement spread over multiple lines, either start the object on the same line (as in foo1), or wrap it in parentheses

```
function foo2() {
  return (
    {
      bar: 'hello'
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: While it's great you want to help, as a steward of SO, you really should vote to close as duplicate rather than provide yet another answer.